# Node.JS and Object.Keys with json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

The Code:

(URL is a working rest api that passes json data)

```
var request = require('request');


var username = "user";
var password = "pass";
var auth = "Basic " + new Buffer(username + ":" + password).toString("base64");



var url = "URL";

request(
    {
        method: "GET",
        url : url
    },
    function (error, response, data) {

          console.log(data);

          var initial_index = Object.keys(data.sites)[0];
          var product_index = Object.keys(data.sites[initial_index].products)[0];

          var order_id = data.purchase_id;
          var title = data.sites[initial_index].products[product_index].title;
          var content = data.sites[initial_index].products[product_index].description;
          var image = data.sites[initial_index].products[product_index].image;
          var total_price = data.sites[initial_index].prices.final_price;
          var quantity = data.sites[initial_index].products[product_index].input_fields.quantity;
          var sold_by = data.sites[initial_index].info.name;
          var order_status = data.sites[initial_index].status;




          var datatwo = {
            "status": "published",
            "order_id": order_id,
            "title": title,
            "content": content,
            "image": image,
            "final_price": total_price,
            "quantity": quantity,  
            "sold_by": sold_by,  
            "order_status": order_status
          };      


    }
);
```

I receive this error when running the code. How can it be resolved?

```
var initial_index = Object.keys(data.sites)[0];
                                 ^

TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

Comment: And how it's look `data`? You can comment body of function and leave only `console.log(data);`.

Answer (score 2):

You're not *parsing* the JSON (which is text) you get back. Add this at the top of your `request` callback:

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
```

E.g.:

```
request(
    {
        method: "GET",
        url : url
    },
    function (error, response, data) {
          data = JSON.parse(data);

          var initial_index = Object.keys(data.sites)[0];

          // ...
```

One you've parsed it, you'll have an object tree you can traverse.

Comment: Thanks T.J. Learning here.